# Jquery clone original HTML not DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, clone

I need to clone a section of markup that has already been modified in the DOM. I want to get the original HTML source - what is seen in View > Source.

clone() uses what's in the DOM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

If you need it, store the original markup in a JavaScript var before making any modifications.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting it in a `variable` before the DOM is manipulated.  I use this method for jQuery templating... `var template = $('#template').html()`

Comment: Note that this line may need to be at the top of the file if you want to catch "script" tags before they execute (eg and create widgets). Also you need to do this in $(document).ready() to be able to use jquery and you want to be at the front of the readyList queue so the line has to be at the top of the file.

Comment: Here is some plain javascript code to do it. It can run immediately before jquery is loaded.

Comment: myHtml = document.getElementById('template').parentNode.innerHTML;

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach would be to preserve the original markup in a hidden `div`.  Then, clone that hidden content.

Another option would be to do an AJAX request to retrieve the original document, then load the HTML you want to duplicate from there.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to copy that HTML into something before the changes are made to the DOM. what the DOM currently has at any given point in time is what you have access to, not past/future versions unless you explicitly saved them to something

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library for this task some time ago :)

http://www.moyablog.com/innerouter-xhtml/

`originalOuterXHTML(element)` will accomplish what you want